# Element count and element data are of different values in java.util.Vector

Tags: java, stack

When I use `java.util.Stack` to add an integer, in debug mode, i find that the element count is one & the elementdata object array is of length 10.
Once the data is pushed into the stack, I see the stack object refers to the length one (i.e elementcount) instead of elementdata array length.

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
stack.push(5);
//Inside the Vector class, i see that add element uses:-
public synchronized void addElement(E obj) {
        modCount++;
        ensureCapacityHelper(elementCount + 1);
        elementData[elementCount++] = obj;
}
```

The elementcount is one & elementData length is 10 
 but the stack.size() is still one. How is the stack object mapped to elementcount?

Comment: `Stack` is backed by an `Array` as shown, which starts out with an initial capacity of 10. This is a trade off of not allocating unnecessary memory, and not allocating enough, which would require copying the `Array` to a new, bigger `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. Because at the beginning `elementData`, by design, is created with a size greater than the actual number of elements it contains: 10 elements in this case.

`elementCount` keeps track of the current number of elements, and as soon as this number is greater than the size of `elementData`, a new array is created with room to spare. This happens every time the current data array gets filled.

The algorithm to increase the size is implementation dependant, some possible examples include: creating a new array with double the size of the original, or creating a new array with 50% more elements. Either way, the elements are copied from the original array to the new one.

Comment: So when i iterate:-
for (int v : stack) {
      System.out.println(v);
  }
It uses Vector.size() method to get the length of the stack. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, in the end `elementCount` is used, because we're interested only in the _actual_ elements and not in the whole array, which will probably contain positions still not in use.